# how to go back to previous activity on back button pressed from youtubestandaloneplayer

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have an activity to display a list of videos from youtube. On clicking an item it plays video using following code. But on pressing back nothing happens. Can anyone tell me how to go back to the previous activity??

---

```
public class VideoPlayer extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
private String videoId;
private static final int REQ_START_STANDALONE_PLAYER = 1;
private final static String DBUG = VideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    videoId = in.getStringExtra("videoId");
    System.out.println("VideoId received :::"+videoId);
    Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, videoId,0,false,false);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.v(DBUG, "Back has been pressed::");
    finishActivity(REQ_START_STANDALONE_PLAYER);
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Oh i found the answer. I used intent in place of initialzing the youtube playerview.

```
private String videoId;
private final static String DBUG = VideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName();
private YouTubePlayerView youtuber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    videoId = in.getStringExtra("videoId");
    System.out.println("VideoId received :::"+videoId);
    youtuber = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youtuber.initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
}
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1,
        boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v(DBUG, "Playing video");
    arg1.cueVideo(videoId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing onBackPressed() to onKeyDown() like that:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.v(DBUG, "Back has been pressed::");
            finishActivity(REQ_START_STANDALONE_PLAYER);
            finish();

    return true;
}
```